# How can I get the calllog date with timestamp for today only in Android?

Tags: android

When I user Cursor to get call duration with Cursor it returns the total times.  To get the length of calls for today only I do try:

```
  public long getTodayTimestamp(){
        Calendar c1=Calendar.getInstance();
        c1.setTime(new Date());
        Calendar c2=Calendar.getInstance();
        c2.set(Calendar.YEAR, c1.get(Calendar.YEAR));
        c2.set(Calendar.MONTH, c1.get(Calendar.MONTH));
        c2.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, c1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
        c2.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
        c2.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        c2.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        return c2.getTimeInMillis();
    }
```

And then do this:

```
String timestap=String.valueOf(getTodayTimestamp());
        Cursor managedCursor =managedQuery(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null,
                null, null, android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DATE + " DESC");
......
```

Which still does not work. How can I return the timestamp for calllog entries for today only.